# Stacked bar plot by proportion/percentage of Species, for Sites and Habitats

Tags: r, ggplot2

Title probably doesn't convey sufficiently my goal.

I have data "*ruvmeans*", which looks like this (sorry, I dont know how to format into a table on here):

[image: data layout]

The top row after the site column is roughly 56 different species.
I am looking to have a bar plot that shows the proportion each species makes up with anything less than 5% being "Other", similar to the layout of this plot:

[image: this plot]

```
ggplot(ruvmeans, aes(x = Group.1, y = value, fill = Group.2)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat= "identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

This is the code I used based on other threads I have read, but "value" is not valid and I am unsure how to transform the data to be able to do this.

Comment: try to learn how to share a piece of your table here (not as a picture), then we'll be able to help. You can, for example, print a fragment by running this command: `print(ruvmeans[1:20,1:10])` - then just copypaste that fragment to your question